# ThreeJs - Texture shows in parts

Tags: three.js

The texture does not show the whole object, Tried use to texture.wrapS and wrapT but nothing.

Full code https://gist.github.com/artur33s/e016acc1cfdbc38d655fb61fcdb4e1bf

```
    // Load Kitchen
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture = textureLoader.load('assets/textures/img.png');
    texture.flipY = false;
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    
    loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
      'assets/3d_models/kitch.glb',
      (gltf) => {
        kitchen = gltf.scene;

        kitchen.traverse((node) => {
          if (node.isMesh) {
            node.material.map = texture;
            console.log(node.material.map);
          }
        });
        // console.log(gltf);
        scene.add(kitchen);
      },
      undefined,
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the whole model has been properly UV mapped?

Comment: texture.repeat.set(0.002, 0.002);  Changet UV its work